# issue in adding click event in a Geolocation

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, user-interface, google-maps-markers

I am working on HTML5 and javascript. and i am developing an application which finds the user's location using google map  and the i am trying to add a click event on the user's location so that when they click they click the message "click here" they must be directed to a new html page. any help or idea would be appreciated.

and here is my code :

```
          <!DOCTYPE html>
       <html>
        <head>
     <title>Getting Geolocation for Weather Details</title>
       <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
       <meta charset="UTF-8">
         <style type="text/css">
        html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  #map_canvas {
    height: 100%;
  }

  @media print {
    html, body {
      height: auto;
    }

    #map_canvas {
      height: 650px;
    }
        }
      </style>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
     var map;

      function initialize() {
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 16,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
        myOptions);

    // Try HTML5 geolocation
    if(navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,
                                         position.coords.longitude);

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
          map: map,
          position: pos,
          content: 'click here'
        });

        map.setCenter(pos);
      }, function() {
        handleNoGeolocation(true);
      });
    } else {
      // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
      handleNoGeolocation(false);
       }
       }

           function handleNoGeolocation(errorFlag) {
    if (errorFlag) {
      var content = 'Error: The Geolocation service failed.';
    } else {
      var content = 'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.';
    }

    var options = {
      map: map,
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(60, 105),
      content: content
    };

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(options);
    map.setCenter(options.position);
      }

      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
       </script>
    </head>
  <body>
     <div id="map_canvas"></div>
       </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Click on `click here` should take to a next page?

Comment: yes. Thats right. they next page is index.html. So when i click that click here it has to navigate to index.html page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this help?

**Replace text with an anchor tag.**

use `content : '<a href="https://www.google.com">click here<a>'` in place of `content : 'click here'` as in -

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    map : map,
    position : pos,
    content : '<a href="https://www.google.com">click here<a>'
});
```

In your case you can put your page link in place of `https://www.google.com`.

Comment: Cool. Thank you verymuch for the solution Moazzam. But is there any way like we can click like normal clickable events. which we usually do in google maps?

Comment: Sorry, I am not much familiar with google maps API, so I cant answer it for now, but you can give `<a>` some `id` and add click listener on it.